# socket communication at separate thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, sockets

I already read 40 pages about threading, but still not sure about my case. 
I have an NSObject, that open a socket connection to a device. This Object handle all the communication, sending and receiving messages and so on. I would like, that this stuff works on separate thread. I tried something like this:

```
- (IBAction)connect:(id)sender {
SocketConnectionController *sock = [SocketConnectionController new];
[[sock initWithParams:ip.text :port.text.intValue] performSelectorInBackground:@selector(initWithParams::) withObject:nil];
[[SocketConnectionController sharedInstance] sendCommand:GET_ID_STRING];
```

}

As you see, I am sending some message by using the existing instance of SocketConnectionController, but it doesn't send anything. There maybe some leak of understanding my side. I am sure, that the connection is open because of flashing lights on device. Am I creating the thread on the right way? If so, how can I use it now?

**1. UPDATE:** 
I tried something like this:

```
NSOperationQueue* queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
SocketConnection *sock = [SocketConnection new];
[queue addOperation:sock];
```

but at the CPU graph I see, that the stuff still running on Thread 1 (mainThread). 
What am I doing wrong?

**2. UPDATE**
I found out, that the run loop, that I need for the Input and Output Stream still running on the main Thread.

```
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

That's why the code of **1. Update** don't work. So I need to create a new Thread and then a new run loop for this thread. That can not be done automatically by Cocoa-Framework like in the code before (performSelectorInBackground).

Comment: If `SocketConnectionController` is a singleton (`sharedInstance`) you shouldn't be calling `new` on it.  Since `new` is `alloc` plus `init`, it's also odd to be calling a second init using parameters.  Finally, the selector to perform shouldn't be yet another init, especially one that takes two parameters instead of the one (`nil`) that you're trying to pass to it.

Comment: so to pass this to parameters I will need something like : performSelectorInBackground:@(initWithParams::) withObject: @"192.168.0.1" withObject:80 ? and how to use this new instance now?

Comment: Why are you even trying to call `initWithParams::` in the background when you've just called it directly?  (And that still doesn't clear up the singleton question.)

Comment: OK. Before I needed a thread I use [[[SocketConnectionController alloc]  initWithParams:ip.text portnr: port.text.intValue];] to create the instance of the socket and it works great. Now I need almost the same only in thread. How to do this?

Comment: I'm guessing because I have no idea what `SocketConnectionController` does internally but can you create it as before and then use `sendCommand` as the thing you want performed in the background (and GET_ID_STRING sent as the `withObject` parameter)?

Comment: initWithParams is a super init of the class, where I CreatePairWithSocketToHost and open input stream and output stream.I have this sharedInstance method, that returns me the actual instance of the class. By using this return, I can use sendCommand method, because it is using the already existing output stream. That way I can send some message from any class. I am not sure about this withObject, because I didn't used some selectors so far.

Comment: The simplest but the most useful threading api within Cocoa is dispatch queues. Check them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way to perform the socket connection on the separate thread:

```
NSThread * nThread;

- (NSThread *)networkThread {
    nThread = nil;

        nThread =
        [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                selector:@selector(networkThreadMain:)
                                  object:nil];
        [nThread start];

    NSLog(@"thread: %@, debug description: %@", nThread, nThread.debugDescription);
    return nThread;
}


- (void)networkThreadMain:(id)unused {
    do {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    } while (YES);
}

- (void)scheduleInCurrentThread:(id)unused
{
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                           forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                           forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

-(BOOL) connectWithError:(NSString **) e
{
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"127.0.0.1", [server port], &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *) readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *) writeStream;

    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];

    [self performSelector:@selector(scheduleInCurrentThread:)
                 onThread:[self networkThread]
               withObject:nil
            waitUntilDone:YES];

    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
}
```

All you need is to input this code in the new class of type NSThread.

Comment: Where was you been two weeks ago? Yeah, CocoaAsyncSocket could be also the solution for this problem.